# UTF-8 string converts non english character to invalid character

Tags: java, arrays, string, encoding, utf-8

I am converting byte array to string with UTF-8 encoding

```
new String(bytearray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

It changes the string `Impresión` to `Impresi�n`. But if i execute below code

```
new String(bytearray);
```

It gives the proper string `Impresión` to `Impresión`

I want to make UTF-8 encoding string without changing any non English character into invalid character.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A- - "Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using the platform's default charset." Your platform default charset may not be UTF-8 (e.g. Windows). If your string is in your platform's' default charset and not in UTF-8 as well, then this behaviour is understandable.

Comment: Are you sure that ```Impresi�n``` is not just an artifact of the shell that outputs your stings? I had such phantom problems with mysql and bash some time ago.

Comment: @luksch I am sure its not from shell output...

Comment: � is a replacement character for bytes that are not valid for the encoding you have specified. It has really helped you out in this case (though exceptions would be better IMO). � is an indicator to your users that you've mishandled their data and lost some of it. So, what's the character encoding for the text in `bytearray`?

Comment: Hi @TomBlodget. It is Spanish text and i am trying convert from bytearray to string. When using UTF_8, it produce invalid char.

Comment: @Kumar � is a completely valid Unicode character. You can't convert bytes to text without knowing the character encoding that was used to convert from text to bytes. So, you need to find out which one it is. Start with where you go the bytes from. There might be a clue there. Look for a communication, convention, specification or standard that applies. The code, of course, would help, too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DocumentBuilder parse produces invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49686444/documentbuilder-parse-produces-invalid-byte-2-of-4-byte-utf-8-sequence-error)

Comment: Hi @TomBlodget, both are different question but the example word are same. When my string contains non English word, i am facing different exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

String objects in Java use the UTF-16 encoding and **cant** be modified.

If you need to use a character from an alternate encoding then you must use a `byte[]` array to store your data, and when you convert it to a string, ensure that you specify the same encoding that was used to encode the byte array.

Therefore when you construct your string from a byte array, you must ensure that the string know how to encode it into UTF-16 from what ever the original encoding was. This is why your first code did not work as in the constructor you specified what the original encoding was and appearently it was not the right encoding, therfore java was unable able to decode the byte array properly. However in the second code you did not specify an encoding, therfore java used the default one on your system which probaly was the same encoding that was used to encode the byte array therefore producing the proper character.

To fix this ensure that the byte array is being encoded with the same encoding that you are specifing when you decode the byte array into a string.

For more information see the below link, particularly the introduction where they write about Strings using the UTF-16 encoding:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: I would not know of characters in other encodings that are not present in unicode - and thus in UTF-16. So yes, you can store characters from other encodings in java strings, but you must take care to get the conversion right...

Answer (score 4):

The format changes because your source byte array is not UTF-8 encoded.
the below code works fine for me.

```
    byte[] bytearray = "Impresión".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String s = new String(bytearray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println(s);
```

and the output is

```
Impresión
```

but when I run below code

```
byte[] bytearray = "Impresión".getBytes();
String s = new String(bytearray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(s);
```

it prints

```
Impresi?n
```

you need to use the same charset for encoding and decoding.