# DocumentBuilder parse produces invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence error

Tags: java, xml, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to parse a bytearray which contains a string `Impresión` in XML

```
final DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
final DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
final Document document;
try (final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytearray)) {
     document = builder.parse(stream); // gives Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence error
}
```

It produces **Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence** error. But when i have Unicode `Impresi\u00f3n`, it works fine. But i want to parse actual character.

Anybody help me to solve it.

Comment: You most probably have an encoding problem. Try wrapping your input stream in a reader and specifying the encoding like `new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytearray), "UTF-8")`.

Comment: @lexicore I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26280313/3496666 but not works

Comment: Please show how do you get `bytearray` from string containing `Impresión`

Comment: Getting string from properties file using ResourceBundle and serialize model class using JAXBContext